# (Baby Rudin) Thm 2.34: Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

[image: Rudin's proof]

At the beginning of proof, $V_q$ should be $V_p$, so it seems to be just typo. Am I right? 
And I have understood up to the part $V=V_{q1} \cap \cdots \cap V_{qn}$ but cannot understand why the $V$ is a "neighborhood" of some $p$. Even though $V_{qi}$'s for $1\leq i \leq n$ are neighborhoods of $qi$'s, I thought the intersection of them doesn't have to be a neighborhood of some $p \in X $, $p \notin K$.

I think the last part of proof should be like "If $V=V_{q1} \cap \cdots \cap V_{qn}$, then since $V$ is the intersection of the neighborhoods, which are open sets, $V$ is an open set, which consists of interior points. Because $V$ does not intersect $W$ by definition, $V \subset K^{c}$, so that every point in $V$ is an interior point of $K^{c}$. The Theorem follows."

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: $V_q$ is a nbhd of $p$ but it depends on $q,$ which explains the $q$  subscript.... E.g. $V_q$ can be the open ball, centered at $p$, of radius $d(p,q)/2$.... Each of $V_{q1},...,V_{qn}$ is a nbhd of $the$ point $p$, so their common intersection $V$ is also a nbhd of $p$.... And $V$ is a nbhd  of $p$ which is disjoint from $K,$ (...because $V\cap K\subset V \cap W$ because $K\subset W$...),  so $p\not \in \bar K.$

Comment: Oh I see. I thought that $p1, p2, p3, ...$ are all different points! Thank you :)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Then, since Rudin says there are finitely many points $q_1, ... , q_n$, are we dealing with several $q_i$ points and one $p$?

Comment: The theorem is a disservice to the student.  It should be compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed.  The proof is the nearly the same.

Comment: We wish to show that any $ p\not \in K$ is also not in $\bar K. $ So we consider any $one$  $p$ and build an argument of the form $p\not  \in K\implies .....\implies p\not \in \bar K.$

Comment: @WilliamElliot. I agree with you on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V_q$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ (not a typo). We see from the letter $V$ that it is. But it does depend on $q$, as its radius is $\frac{d(p,q)}{2}$, which only is done to ensure that $V_q \cap W_q = \emptyset$ for all $q \in K$ (this is all we will need). So we know that the $V$ neighbourhood of $p$ and the corresponding $W_q$ neighbourhood (i.e. with the same subscript $q$) of $q$ are disjoint.

All of the sets $V_{q_1}, V_{q_2},\ldots, V_{q_n}$ are balls around $p$ (the fixed $p \notin K$ we start with!) of varying radii. So their intersection $V$ is also an open ball (of radius equal the minimum of these finitely many radii) and thus an open neighbourhood of $p$ as well.

If now $x \in K$, then $x \in W_{q_i}$ for some $q_i \in \{q_1, \ldots, q_n\}$ (these are finitely many distinct points of $K$ such that their corresponding $W_{q_i}$ open balls are a finite cover of $K$ (the existence of those is ensured by $K$ being compact) and then $V = V_{q_1} \cap \ldots V_{q_n} \subseteq V_{q_i}$ and $V_{q_i}$ and $W_{q_i}$ (same index point!) are disjoint so $x  \notin V$. As $x \in K$ was arbitrary, $K \cap V = \emptyset$.

So we see that each $p \notin K$ is an interior point of $K^c$, so $K^c$ is open and so $K$ is closed.

Comment: This a perfect answer that I really want. Thank you for your great help! :D

Comment: @Hunnam It is possible to accept and upvote answers...

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean not to upvote the answer! I just did it!